# PHPでgmailにメール送信をしたいが送ることが出来ない

Tags: php

お願いします。

PHPで、gmail宛にメールを送りたいのですが、上手くいきません。

学校のサーバ上で動くプログラムです。

mb_send_mailでFALSEが返って来たら「送信失敗」と出すはずなのですが、
「メールが送信されました」と表示されます。
エラーは出ません。

php.iniの編集部分です。

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
;SMTP = localhost
SMTP = mail.～

smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

;;;;;   メール送信元を設定する
sendmail_from = ～@~
;;;;;

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

都合上書けない所は「～」と変更させていただいています。
「～」の部分は間違っていない前提でのお話で結構です。
(後日別の者にしっかりと確認していただく予定です。)

受け取り・メール送信側のソースコードです。
項目の入力画面は別ファイルで行っています。

```
<?php
//print ini_get('sendmail_from');
//var_dump(ini_get('sendmail_from'));
//$a = ini_get('sendmail_from');
/*
if($a == null)
{
    print "aaa";
}
*/
$message = "名前：" . $_POST["name"] . "\n本文：" . $_POST["message"];
$mail = "aaa@gmail.com";
if (!mb_send_mail($mail, $_POST["subject"], $message, "From: " . print ini_get('sendmail_from')))
{
  exit("送信失敗");
}

?>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>送信結果</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>メールが送信されました。</p>
</body>
</html>
```

コードの

```
//print ini_get('sendmail_from');
//var_dump(ini_get('sendmail_from'));
//$a = ini_get('sendmail_from');
/*
if($a == null)
{
    print "aaa";
}
*/
```

この部分で試しましたが、sendmail_fromが空になっています。
原因の一つにこれがあると考えていますが、対処出来ませんでした。

足りない所、間違っている所はあるでしょうか？
また、可能性として考えられる事は何でしょうか？
なんでも良いので教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `php.ini` の `sendmail_from` がコメントアウトされていますので、`ini_get('sendmail_from')` は空文字("")を返します。`mb_send_mail` の `ini_get('sendmail_from')` の部分には具体的なメールアドレス(送信元メールアドレス)を指定すれば良いのではないでしょうか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。「;」と「;」で囲われている部分はコメントアウトされると言う事でしょうか？そうだとすれば確かにsendmail_fromが2つともコメントアウトされていてから文字が返される事に納得です。
確認してみます。

Comment: 失礼、直下の設定を見落としていました。確かに`ini_get('sendmail_from')` は `～@~` を返すはずですが、何も返さないとの事ですので一行目の `print ini_get('sendmail_from');` を `print ini_get('SMTP');` とした場合に、`php.ini` で設定した SMTP サーバのホスト名を返すかどうか確認してもらえますか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
localhostが返ってきました。これは今現在がローカル環境で行われているからなのでしょうか？もしコメントアウトされているのにlocalhostが返ってきているのはおかしいという事でしたら、別の場所にphp.iniが存在していて、そっちを参照しているということになるのでしょうか

Comment: はい、その可能性が高いです。`print php_ini_loaded_file();` を入れると実際に読み込んでいる `php.ini` のパスが分かりますので確認してみて下さい。

Comment: それと、`mb_send_mail(..., "From: " . print ini_get('sendmail_from'))` の `print` は必要ありません。`mb_send_mail(..., "From: " . ini_get('sendmail_from'))`

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
windowsフォルダの直下にあるphp.iniだけでなく、xampp\php\の中にもphp.iniがあり、そちらを読み込んでいました。
本日中に試してみたいと思います。
引数の中にプリントは必要無いという事なのでしょうか。
勉強になります。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

皆様コメント、回答ありがとうございます。

今回メールが送れなかったのは、編集していたphp.iniが違った事が原因でした。

```
print php_ini_loaded_file();
```

こちらで実際に取り込んでいるphp.iniを確認し、そちらを編集し直しました。

Answer (score 1):

以下の点は問題ありませんか？
・学校の当該サーバの発信IPに対してSPFが設定されているか
・sendmailのコマンドの引数に -f オプションでUNIX FROMを正しいものにしているか
・当該サーバはlocalhostのメールをrelayする設定となっているか。
  (メールサーバのログはどうなっていますか？)
・nslookup -type=mx gmail.com で出力されるメールサーバに telnet  25 で接続可能か

Comment: 回答有り難うございます。
既に送れている人もいるので、ご指摘の件に関しては問題無いと思っていますが、念のために確認しておきたいと思います。